# Behat multiple profile

Tags: php, behat

Im having `behat.yml` which looks like

```
machine:
  suites:
    machine:
      contexts:
        - MachineContext:
location:
  suites:
    location:
      contexts:
        - LocationContext:
```

And when I run `behat -c behat.yml --profile machine` it run all my scenarios correct, but when I run `behat -c behat.yml --profile location` it run scenarios rom `location.feature` and adds scenariose form `machine.feature` and tells me that Im missing then

Comment: Are you using symfony?

Comment: @BentCoder no Im not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I needed to add `paths` in my profile configuration, now my `behat.yml` looks like

```
machine:
  suites:
    machine:
      paths:
        - %paths.base%/features/machine.feature
      contexts:
        - MachineContext:
location:
  suites:
    location:
      paths:
        - %paths.base%/features/location.feature
      contexts:
        - LocationContext:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inspire from this example. Adjust it for your needs.

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      sessions:
        default:
          symfony2: ~
    Behat\Symfony2Extension:
      kernel:
        env: test
        debug: true

machine:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: 'http://machine.domain.com/app_test.php/'
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - Path/To/Your/Context/Machine1Context:
          - 'constructor parameter if you have any'
          - 'and another one'
        - 'Path/To/Your/Context/Machine2Context'

      type: symfony_bundle
      bundle: Whatever1YourBundle

location:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: 'http://location.domain.com/app_test.php/'
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - 'Path/To/Your/Context/LocationContext'

      type: symfony_bundle
      bundle: Whatever2YourBundle
```

Or you can just use `suites` version like here: [Installing behat3 with composer.json](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/v2zi/installing-behat3-with-composer-json)

Answer (score 0):

works for me by adding following command :

```
behat -c behat.yml --profile machine --suite=machine

behat -c behat.yml --profile machine --suite=location
```